# How to find lambda function's invocation event?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I have a lambda function that is written by the dev team.

I want to test its log format using cloudwatch logs insights, my problem is that how I test lambda with proper error code and description which are needed to be verified in log format.

All I have is a previous log entry for the month of May, is there a way to find the event used in order to invoke lambda function?

Comment: Real event, or some fake one?

Comment: Since the system is in production, real event is not possible, so it would be nice if I can simulate a real event, to check its log format.